# Multiple Cameras in SteamVR HTC vive

Tags: unity-game-engine

I need to have multiple cameras in a Unity3d scene. However every time i create a camera, SteamVR automatically overrides it so that it is moving with the helmet. I simply need a normal camera without steamVR taking over it. How can that be done?

Answer (score 0):

Note, assuming Unity here:

Simply, don't make it the main camera. You can also disable VR support in project player settings and use the SteamVR plugin's CameraRig.